# Can I create multiple unique instances of the Newsfeed web part in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, web-part, newsfeed

We've just been upgraded to Sharepoint 2013 and I am finding the Newsfeed feature to be very handy. So much, in fact, I would like to add a separate instance for the other non-interacting departments (example: one for my IT department and another for our community outreach coordinators). I have enabled the Site Feed feature and created a second Newsfeed web part however, it just repopulates the posts and information from the Newsfeed web part on the home page. How can I create multiple unique instances of the Newsfeed web part so IT can have a completely different conversation than our social media group or marketing departments without creating entire sub-sites for each department?

I would also mention that I am not a developer and I am not using Powershell.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do that. Each site is configured to use the Microfeed list for news feeds

Answer (score 3):

We've looked into this as well, and it appears the only way to do it is to create subsites. The newsfeed is a site feature (Site Feed), so it is only allowed one instance per site. Creating a subsite creates another instance, e.g. a new newsfeed, for that site specifically. Team sites would be the best bet since the content you are trying to cordon off is team-specific, and they include the newsfeed by default.

Answer (score 3):

We could do that by applying this method:

1- Create Subsite and Enable “Site Feed” feature.

2- Add “Site Feed” WebPart in the new Subsite

3- Go to Main Site and do the same “Enable Site Feed Feature” and “Add Site Feed to home Page”.

4- In the main Site, add “Page Viewer” webpart and put as a link the page created before which contains Subsite Feed”.

5- We can see now two feeds in the same page, and it works because the second one is iframe that uses another JavaScript context.

6- The main problem is we have the Ribbon, Title, Navigation, etc… in the iframe, but we can remove it by creating a new Master Page and/or Layout and change it only for this subsite and page.

7- You can download an example of empty master page here: http://josharepoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/EmptyMasterPageSample.zip

8- Upload this example to /_catalogs/masterpage and change that content type to Master Page, After that, Publish it and will be able to use this master page in your SubSite.

More information:
http://josharepoint.com/2015/03/30/add-multiple-newsfeeds-site-feed-webparts-in-a-sharepoint-2013-page/